# Como transformar(ou concatenar) os elementos de um array em um valor numérico usando JavaScript? Estou tentando usar o método reduce()

Tags: javascript, array

Eu quero transformar os elementos de um array em um único número, mas não pode ser a soma de todos os elementos desse array. Eu preciso concatenar todos os elementos do array e transformar eles em um único valor numérico, por exemplo:

```
const numeros = [2, 5, 6]
```

Deve retornar o valor numérico de 256.

Eu tentei fazer da seguinte maneira:

```
const numeros = [2, 5, 6];

const valor = numeros.reduce((accumulator, number) => accumulator.concat(number));
```

A expectativa era de obter o valor numérico 256, mas ocorre um erro, alguém pode me ajudar?

Comment: `Number(numeros.join(''))`.

Comment: Se não quiser usar strings, pode usar o `reduce` e ir somando o valor correspondente a cada potência de dez. Não fica tão elegante porque os índices são "invertidos". `[2, 5, 6].reduce((acc, curr, i, arr) => acc + curr * 10 ** (arr.length - (i + 1)), 0);` Não dá para usar o `concat` como você tenta fazer na pergunta porque não existe método `concat` no protótipo de números em JavaScript.

Comment: Resumindo: ou faz malabarismos com strings, ou faz malabarismos de sintaxe :)

Comment: Não sei porque existe essa "obsessão" por usar `reduce`, sendo que um loop simples já resolve (além de deixar o código bem mais fácil de entender, na minha opinião): https://ideone.com/zNJiHs

Comment: @hkotsubo, argumentos frequentes que vejo são, por exemplo, deixar em uma só expressão e evitar a _temida_ mutabilidade. Claro que nesse caso a diferença é irrisória e dá para colocar numa função, mas às vezes é legal como exercício, e não necessariamente "obsessão": `[2, 5, 6].reduce((total, n) => total * 10 + n, 0)`. Esse é um caso no qual o `reduce` se encaixa perfeitamente. Eu pessoalmente acho isso mais fácil de ler que um código que ocupa várias linhas, mas talvez eu esteja enviesado pela igreja funcional, hehe.

Comment: @LuizFelipe Acho que os argumentos não se aplicam aqui. O código não modifica o array, e é tão simples que não tem mais o que enxugar (deixar em uma linha é um preciosismo desnecessário). Mas eu também estou enviesado, o paradigma funcional tem pontos positivos mas acho que às vezes é super-valorizado e raros são os casos em que uso `reduce`. E como a linguagem já dá uma alternativa mais simples (o bom e velho loop), prefiro usá-la. E só citei a "obsessão" porque me parece que muita gente vê o `reduce` como primeira (ou única, ou "melhor") opção para resolver tudo, e isso eu acho um erro...

Answer (score -1):

Eu consegui encontrar essa solução, aqui está funcionando bem, mas eu aceito opiniões para saber se esse método é uma boa prática de desenvolvimento.

```
const numeros = [2, 5, 6];

const valor = numeros.reduce((accumulator, number) => `${accumulator}${number}`);

const numCriado = Number(valor);
```

O valor retornado é o número 256 com eu estava querendo

Comment: Você juntou os dois malabarismos que comentei acima na pergunta :)

Comment: Pra ficar bem claro, você juntou o pior dos dois mundos. Não precisa usar reduce E manipulação de string, são duas indireções desnecessárias. Ou use reduce e lide apenas com valores numéricos (sugestão do Luiz Felipe), ou use strings (minha sugestão com join no comentário da pergunta).

Comment: @bfavaretto Obrigado pela sugestão, eu alterei o meu código e agora estou usando o método join(), veja como ficou:                                                       

const nums = [2, 5, 6];

const valorNum = nums.join('');

const numRecebido = Number(valorNum);

A variável numRecebido retorna o número 256 como eu estava querendo.